# Evaluate Linux file copy command in c

Tags: c, linux, file-io, cp

I have the following program below which copies the whole text file of the one to another where you input the name of the source file and the destination file. I need to modify my program to evaluate the Linux cp command.

My `subcopy` command will take as a parameter the name of a **source file**, the name of a **destination file** and the **beginning and end lines** of the source file lines that will be copied to the destination file, like the example below:

> subcopy.o Sourcefile.txt destinationfile.txt 100 200
>
> Copied lines 100 - 200 from Sourcefile.txt to destinationfile.txt

**Edited**: I have done all the hard work. What is left is to choose the number of lines I want to copy from the one file to the other. Notice the example how it works.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
 
 
 void cp(char source_file[],char destination_file[],int lines_copy)
 {
      
      char ch;
   FILE *source, *destination;
 
  
   
 
   source = fopen(source_file, "r");
 
   if( source == NULL )
   {
      printf("File name not found, make sure the source file exists and is ending at .txt\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
 
   
 
   destination = fopen(destination_file, "w" );
 
   if( destination == NULL )
   {
      fclose(source);
      printf("Press any key to exit...\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
 
   while( ( ch = fgetc(source) ) != EOF )
      fputc(ch, destination);
 
   printf("Copied lines %d  from %s to %s \n",lines_copy,source_file,destination_file,".txt");
 
   fclose(source);
   fclose(destination);

 }
 
int main()
{


    char s[20];
    char d[20];
    int lines;
    
    printf("-Enter the name of the source file ending in .txt\n-Enter the name of the destination file ending in .txt\n-Enter the number of lines you want to copy\n\n");
            
     printf(">subcopy.o ");
    gets(s);
       printf("destination file-> ");
        gets(d);
        printf("Lines: ");
        scanf("%d",&lines);
      
    cp(s,d,lines);
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    return 0;
    
 }
```

Comment: search in google "linux copy file command"

Comment: ok maybe I'm wrong, I changed the title to copy command

Comment: thanks for edit @Am_I_Helpful

Comment: Why are you calling `access()`?  At best, it's useless,  At worst, such an approach leads to [a time-of-check/time-of-use (TOCTOU) bug.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_check_to_time_of_use)

Comment: Maybe you need to to something like this and modify the lines you want to copy: http://www.programmingsimplified.com/c-program-copy-file

Comment: **DON'T USE `gets`** specialy with small buffers... And the code is only loosely related to the question: copy from first to last in question copy n lines in code.

Answer (score 1):

Mmap file and search for offsets to certain line number. Since mapped file really is memory, there's no extra storage procedure once offsets are found.
I have written a small code to get line number. You have to modify the code for copying data into destination file.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <err.h>

/* following code assumes all file operations succeed. In practice,
 * return codes from open, close, fstat, mmap, munmap all need to be
 * checked for error.
*/
int read_file_line(const char *path, int line_no)
{
    struct stat s;
    char *buf;
    off_t start = -1, end = -1;
    size_t i;
    int ln, fd, ret = 1;

    if (line_no == 1) start = 0;
    else if (line_no < 1){
        warn("line_no too small");
        return 0; /* line_no starts at 1; less is error */
    }

    line_no--; /* back to zero based, easier */

    fd = open(path, O_RDONLY);
    fstat(fd, &s);

    buf = mmap(0, s.st_size, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 0);

    /* optional; if the file is large, tell OS to read ahead */
    madvise(buf, s.st_size, MADV_SEQUENTIAL);

    for (i = ln = 0; i < s.st_size && ln <= line_no; i++) {
        if (buf[i] != '\n') continue;

        if (++ln == line_no) start = i + 1;
        else if (ln == line_no + 1) end = i + 1;
    }

    if (start >= s.st_size || start < 0) {
        warn("file does not have line %d", line_no + 1);
        ret = 0;
    } else {
        /*  Do Copy data from this block into destination */
    }

    munmap(buf, s.st_size);
    close(fd);

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: *use seek command to 100 position.*  The command in question works in lines, not bytes.  You can't seek to *byte* offsets and expect to match lines.

Comment: @AndrewHenle thanks to correct me, I have edited my post. even i wrote a simple code to find line number within a file.

Answer (score 0):

Why bother writing a program to do this? You can do this with a simple bash command:

```
SOURCE=/path/to/source/file
DEST=/path/to/dest/file
START=100
END=200

tail -n +$START $SOURCE | head -n $(( $END - $START )) > $DEST
```

Comment: can you be more specific?

Comment: I want to to this in c m8

Comment: You don't need to do this in C; you can use standard commands.

Comment: *Why* do you want to do this in C?

Comment: Because I am not doing this for me :)